# Build JObject from iterative path

Tags: json.net

I need to dynamically build a object that I can then serialize to a JSON string. Essentially I'm working off of two Dictionaries that I need to use to create the new object.

```
var myValues= new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Value1", "Foo" },
    { "Value2", "Bar" }
};
var mappedValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Value1", "Some:Path" },
    { "Value2", "Some:OtherPath }
};
```

As I loop through I need to be able to build out the Json Object so that I end up with something like:

```
{
  "Some": {
    "Path": "Foo",
    "OtherPath": "Bar"
  }
}
```

From what I've seen there is no way built into Newtonsoft.Json to do this specifically, but I'm hoping that someone may have an idea of how I might be able to most efficiently accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem that there is any sort of way to create an element built into Newtonsoft.Json at this time... however I eventually came up with the following solution which works

```
private JObject DoFoo()
{
    var jObject = new JObject();
    foreach(var mapping in mappedValues)
    {
        var queue = new Queue<string>(mapping.Value.Split(':');
        var value = myValues[mapping.Key];
        SetValueWithPath(jObject, queue, value);
    }

    return jObject;
}

private void SetValueWithPath(JObject parent, Queue<string> path, object content)
{
    var currentNode = path?.FirstOrDefault();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentNode)) return;

    if (path.Count == 1)
    {
        parent[currentNode] = JToken.FromObject(content);
        return;
    }
    else if (!parent.ContainsKey(currentNode))
    {
        parent[currentNode] = new JObject();
    }

    path.Dequeue();
    SetValueWithPath(parent[currentNode] as JObject, path, content);
}
```